# Laravel 5 - SQL error on Timestamps with M:N relationship

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, laravel-5

I have a table for the model `User` and another for the model `Feature`.

I want users to vote on features, so I create a table for it:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('votes', function(Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id');

        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('feature_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('feature_id')->references('id')->on('features')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I define the relationship on the `Feature` model:

```
public function votes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'votes');
}
```

In the controller, I try  to execute a vote for the user logged in.

```
public function vote(Feature $feature) {
    $feature->votes()->save(Auth::user());
}
```

But when I execute this action, I get the following message:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: votes.created_at (SQL: insert into "votes" ("feature_id", "user_id") values (1, 1))

If I read the message, it would seem as if the `created_at` field isn't being filled, but those fields are usually automatically handled by Laravel.

What did I mess?

Comment: can you confirm that there's no ``$timestamps = false;`` in ``Feature`` model?

Comment: neither in `Feature` nor in `User`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to use timestamps on a pivot table you must declare that on the model method.

```
public function votes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'votes')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Comment: You, Sir, are my hero! :)